# Show that there is such a Sylow subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I want to show that if $G$ is finite and $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a group epimorphism and if $Q\in \text{Syl}_p(H)$ then there is a $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ with $Q=f(P)$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have that $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a group epimorphism, so $f$ is surjective. That means that for every $y\in H$ there is a $x\in G$ such that $f(x)=y$. So, we have that $H\leq G$.

We have that $Q\in \text{Syl}_p(H)$. Suppose that $|H|=p^ma$, where $p\not\mid a$. That means that $|Q|=p^m$.

$$$$

Could you give me a hint how we could continue?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

From the first isomorphism theorem we have that $H\cong G/\ker f$.

SInce $Q\in \text{Syl}_p(H)$ we have that $Q\leq H$.

So, there is subgroup of $G$, say $U$, such that $Q=f(U)$.

From the correspondence theorem we have that $\ker f\leq U$.

From the correspondence theorem we have also that $[G:U]=[H:Q]$.

Let $P\in \text{Syl}_p(U)$, then we have that $[G:P]=[G:U][U:P]$.

We have that $[G:U]$ and $[U:P]$ are not divisible by $p$.

Therefore, $[G:P]$ is not divisible by $p$.

That means that $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$, right?

Since $P\leq U$ we have that $f(P)\leq f(U)=Q$.

But how could we show that $Q=f(P)$ ?

Comment: Let  $F = \phi^{-1}(Q) = \{ g \in G \mid \phi(g) \in Q \}$. Then $K = \ker \phi \le F$ and $K/F \cong Q$ and $|G:K| = |H:Q| = a$. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(F)$. Then $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $\phi(P)=Q$.

Comment: Why does it hold that $\ker\phi\leq F$ and that $K/F\cong Q$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: $\ker \phi \le F$ is true by definition of $F$, and $K/F \cong Q$ is the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: With $\phi$ you mean $f$, right? How do we know that the inverse $f^{-1}$ exist? $$$$ Since $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a group epimorphism and $Q$ is a subgroup of $H$, does it always stand that there is a group $F$ such that $Q=f(F)$ or equivalently $F=f^{-1}(Q)$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: Yes sorry I meant $f$ not $\phi$. The definition of $f^{-1}(Q)$ is $\{ g \in G : f(g) \in  Q \}$.  This is a subgroup of $G$ with $f^{-1}(Q)/\ker(f) \cong Q$.

Comment: Ah ok... You said at your first post that $|G:K| = |H:Q| $. Shouldn't it be $|G:F| = |H:Q| $ ? $$$$ Also, why does it stand that $f(P)=Q$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: When $f(P)=Q$, and we have also that $f(F)=Q$, do we conclude that $F=P$ ? @DerekHolt

Comment: I haven't really understood why we suppose that $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(F)$... Could you explain it to me? Can it not be that $F$ is a subgroup of $P$?  @DerekHolt

Answer (score 3):

Remember the correspondence theorem, and also $\;H\cong G/\ker f\;$ , so if we have

$\;Q\in Syl_p(H)=Syl_p(G/\ker f)\;$ , then there exists $\;K\le G\;$ such that

$$\ker f\le K\;,\;\;K/\ker f=Q\;,\;\;[H:Q]=[G:K]$$$${}$$

If we now take $\;P\in Syl_p(K)\;$ , then we get $\;[G:P]=[G:K][K:P]\;$ , but$${}$$

$$\begin{cases}[G:K]=[H:Q]\,\sim\,\text{coprime with}\;p\;\,\text{since}\,\;Q\in Syl_p(H)\\{}\\{}[K:P]\,\sim\,\text{coprime with $\,p\,$ since}\;P\in Syl_p(K)\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\;\text{gcd}\,\left([G:P],\,p\right)=1$$$${}$$

and thus we get $\;P\in Syl_p(G)\;$ .

Comment: This is not right because $\ker f$ is not necessarily a $p$-group so it is not true that $\ker f \le P$. You need to take a Sylow $p$-subgroup of the inverse image of $Q$ under $f$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I think I see your point, I shall edit now....but I see this is practically the same as your argument in the comment. Ok, I'll edit and then, if needed, I will erase.

Comment: Why does it hold that $\;H\cong G/\ker f\;$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar First Isomorphism theorem, of course.

Comment: Since $H$ is isomorphic to $G/\ker f$, we have that $|\text{Syl}_p(H)|=|\text{Syl}_p(G/\ker f)|$, right? But we do not conclude that $\text{Syl}_p(H)=\text{Syl}_p(G/\ker f)$, do we?

Comment: Also, at $K/\ker f=Q$ do you mean equality or isomorphism?

Comment: I haven't really understood why we take that $\;P\in Syl_p(K)\;$... Could you explain it to me? Can it not be that $K$ is a subgroup of $P$?

Comment: @MaryStar Excuse me but I find this a little exhausting: you seem to be having lots of problems with very, very basic things that should, in my opinion, be well understood before attempting problems of this kind. Of course isomorphic groups have the same number of Sylow subgroups for some given prime, and $\;Q=K/\ker f\;$ is equality or isomorphism: it all depends on the grade of formality, on definitions...and it really isn't that important *in this case*, and we take $\;P\in Syl_p(K)\;$ because is a group we can tell something about **and also** because this precise group is ...

Comment: ...what will be a Sylow subgroup of the whole group, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Since $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $U$, we have that $P$ has a prime power order, say $p^i$. Since $[G:P]$ is coprime with $p$, we know that at the prime factorization of $|G|$ the maximal power of $p$ is $i$, or not? That's why $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$, right?

Comment: But why does it hold that $Q=f(P)$ ? Do we use the fact that all $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugated?

Comment: @MaryStar Who says that holds?

Comment: Are we not supposed to show it according to the problem statement?

Comment: We have that $U$ and $P$ are $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. That means that these two are conjugate, right? Therefore, $P=gUg^{-1}$, for some $g\in G$, right? Do we have to show that $g=1$ ?