# Do we conclude in that way that it is a $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am looking at the following exercise:

If $G$ is finite and $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a group epimorphism, show that if $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ then $f(P)\in \text{Syl}_p(H)$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Since $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$, we have that $P$ is a subgroup of $G$. Do we have from the correspondence theorem that $f(P)$ is a subgroup of $H$ ?

Suppose that this is true.

From the correspondence theorem we also have that $[G:P]=[H:f(P)]$, right?

Since $P\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$, we have that $[G:P]$ is coprime with $p$.

That means that $[H:f(P)]$ is also coprime with $p$. Do we conclude in that way that $f(P)$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ ?

Comment: The image of any subgroup is a subgroup of the image. So $f(P)$ is a group.

Comment: Do we get it from the correspondence theorem? Or does this always hold? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: If $H\le G$ then $f(H)\le f(G)$. I'm not sure which result you mean by the correspondence theorem.

Comment: I found in my notes the following about that theorem: 

$$f:G\rightarrow H \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ | \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ | \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ U\leftrightarrow T=f(U) \\ | \ \ \ \ \ \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ K=\ker f$$ 

If $X=\{U\leq G/ K\leq U\leq G\}, Y=\{T\leq H\}$ 

There is a 1-1 and onto mapping $X\leftrightarrow Y$, $UU\rightarrow f(U)$. 
$$$$ 
The following hold: 
$$$$ 
1) $[G:U]=[H:f(U)]$ 
$$$$ 
2) $U\trianglelefteq G \Leftrightarrow f(U)\trianglelefteq H$ 
$$$$ 
3) If $U\trianglelefteq G$ then $G/U\cong H/f(U)$

Comment: In this case we cannot use 2) because the subgroup isn't normal, right? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: That's right but you can use (1).

Comment: Yes, as I used it in my original post, right? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: So, is after that point everything correct in my initial post? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: I believe so. You probably want to say why $f(P)$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: You mean the justification of your first comment? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Not just that $f(P)$ is a group, you can get that from the correspondence thm, but that it's also a $p$-group.

Comment: How can we get that? I got stuck right now... @TimRaczkowski

Comment: $f(P)\cong P/(P\cap\ker f)$.

Comment: How do we show this isomorphism? Why does this hold? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Let $g=f|P$, and $Q=f(P)$. Then $g:P\to Q$ is surjective.  So, $Q\cong P/\ker g$.  But $\ker g=P\cap\ker f$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $N=ker(f)$. Because $f$ is surjective, by the first isomorphism theorem $f(G)=H=G/N$. Observe that $f(P)=PN/P$. We argue that this is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$. Since $PN/N \cong P/(P \cap N)$, we see that $f(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup. Also $|H:f(P)|=|G/N:PN/N|=|G:PN|$. And this last index divides $|G:P|$, since we have a chain of subgroups $G \supseteq PN \supseteq P$. Hence $|H:f(P)|$ is not divisible by $p$, and we conclude that $f(P) \in Syl_p(H)$.

Comment: Why does it hold that $f(P)=PN/P$ ?